# Can't transform 2D array to 1D in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, flatten

So I wanto to multiply a vector (1D array) by a rotation matrix (2D array) but the resulted vector turns out 2D. `flatten` or `ravel` for some reason still return a 2D array.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([5, 5, 0])

Rx = np.matrix([[1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 1]])
b = a * Rx
b = b.flatten()

print(b)
```

Instead of `[5 5 0]` I get `[[5 5 0]]`

Is there any better solution other than `c = np.array([b[0, 0], b[0, 1], b[0, 2]])` ?

Comment: Instead of using `matrix`, use a regular array.

Comment: …in addition to @MechanicPig's advice, consider `b = a @ Rx` for matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([5, 5, 0])

Rx = np.matrix([[1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 1]])
b = a * Rx
b = np.array(b).flatten()

print(b)
```

Otherwise you can convert matrix to array and can use flatten for it as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use np.matrix use b =np.array(equation) so you can use your b variable easier.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([5, 5, 0])

Rx = np.matrix([[1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 1]])
b = np.array(a * Rx).flatten()

print(b)
```